# Google places API only returns 2 results

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I am trying to use Ggoogle Places API to return the nearest cities/towns to a set of coordinates.

```
  $nearbySearchUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" . http_build_query([
      'location' => $latitude . ',' . $longitude,
      'radius' => 50000,
      'type' => 'locality',
      'key' => $apiKey,
  ]);
```

The code is working, however whatever params I send I only ever get two results returned. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you also provide the latlngs you have used? And what is its results? What is the expected behavior? That would greatly help! :'>

Comment: If you take a look at the [List of Supported Tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table1) `type=locality` is only available using Place Details and Autocomplete(partly). Place Search only supports Table 1 in the list.